# What difference does it make when match_max is specified after or before spawing ssh?

Tags: linux, buffer, expect

```
# match_max 1000000000
  set timeout 60
  spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "$username@$hostname"
  match_max 1000000000
```

If match_max option is given before i use ssh i don't get the complete output into the `expect_out(buffer)` but if I give the same thing after SSH I get correct results.

Also, if i use -d option in the first case I get the complete output. Why?

Also, how can I check how much buffer is set for my Linux system? I looked for `limit` command but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for expect regarding the `match_max` command reads

```
match_max [-d] [-i spawn_id] [size]
defines the size of the buffer (in bytes) used internally by expect. With no size argument, the current size is returned. With the -d flag, the default size is set. (The initial default is 2000.) With the -i flag, the size is set for the named spawn id, otherwise it is set for the current process.
```

This is exactly what you're observing (since `-i` isn't specified).